# Display problem after installaling updates in ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, installation, 12.10, screen

I had installed Ubuntu 12.10 yesterday but it was not working properly, so installed Ubuntu 12.04 from Live USB and after installation, it was working without harm, but problems arose when I installed updates, the screen is going weird if I launch dash home.

I've posted link of screen shot of my screen, hoping that this problem can be solved. http://samsher.xtgem.com/pics/problem.png Take a look at top of the screen, there you can see the problem.

`lspci -nn | grep VGA output`

```
00:0d.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: NVIDIA Corporation C61 [GeForce 7025 / nForce 630a] [10de:03d6] (rev a2)
```

Comment: Can you add the hardware specs, and please, don't forget the graphics card model.

Comment: Hardware, Memory: 1.9 GiB  Processor: AMD Athlon(tm) II X2 240 Processor x 2, graphic driver Unknown :(, it is working fine in 2D.

Comment: That's helpful, thatnk, but it lacks the graphics info. Can you add the output of `lspci -nn | grep VGA` to the question - please don't post it in the comments. Generally, as Unity requires decent 3d support, it won't work well with quite a few GPUs. That's why Unity2d was made.

Comment: added output in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, you have an oldish Nvidia card from around 2006. Originally, the [6xxx and 7xxx series didn't work at all with Unity](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nvidia-graphics-drivers/+bug/728745), now some of them do, but as you can see, not very well. Unity is targeted at more recent GPUs - 3-4 years back, to give an optimistic estimation.

I'd advise using Unity2d, or any of the Ubuntu derivatives - Kubuntu, Xubuntu, Lubuntu.

Comment: ok, thanks for information, i am noob about graphic card and all, so can i upgrade my graphic card? what you say?

Comment: Sure, theoretically, anything can be upgraded, the big question - is it worth it. What you have is probably an on-board GPU (in other words, soldered to the board), so, you'll need to open up the computer case and check if there is a slot for an external graphics card.

Comment: oh ok i will try it one day, but not now, thanks again for information.